# How to config react to watch for changes in css files with npm-watch

Tags: reactjs, npm, tailwind-css

I have installed react and tailwind and I can not configure npm-watch to watch for css files. If I change js files is ok but not for css.

This is my package.json. I have tried many different ways to config but no luck

```
    "watch": {
    "css": {
      "patterns": [ "src/styles"],
      "extenstions": "css",
      "runOnChangeOnly": false,
      "quiet":true
    },
    "build": {
      "patterns": ["src"],
      "extensions": "js,jsx",
      "runOnChangeOnly": false,
      "quiet":true
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:style": "tailwind build src/styles/index.css -o src/styles/tailwind.css",
    "start": "npm run build:style && react-scripts start && npm run watch",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "watch": "watch && npm run build:style"
  },
```

Comment: Should your command not be `build:style` as opposed to `css`? (line 2)

Comment: I will try thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue wasn't with the npm-watch or with the config file. If you wish to read a css file you have to import that file. That is all. In index.js import css.

```
import './styles/tailwind.css'; 
import './styles/index.css';
```